# In-app purchases still frozen?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm having problems testing my in-app purchases for an app for mine.
I've done this before without any problems, but now it suddenly seems impossible.

And whilst doing some googling, I was made aware of the in-app patent trouble that Apple has had and their freezing of in-app purchases in May.

I'm wondering if anybody know the state of things in this matter? Am I unable to test my IAPs
because things are still frozen from Apple's side or is my problem code related?

Comment: Uh, what? IAP frozen since May? I don't think so.

Comment: They froze IAPs for a short period in May - wondering if this can be a case at the moment too.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You'd do better to ask Apple or post in a Apple forum.

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished development of a new iOS application.  It uses in-app purchase to download content.  I have successfully tested it and it works even today.  There must be something wrong with your code or your setup in iTunes Connect.

Perhaps if you can describe the problem you are experiencing, and post some code you are using, someone here can help more thoroughly.

**EDIT**: As a follow-up.  If you are new to In-app Purchase and looking for a good walk-through, I recommend that you get a book called The Business of iPhone and iPad Development.  It's listed here: http://www.apress.com/9781430233008.  It has a great section on In-app Purchase.